# Spark count dataframe to estimate output partitions, then write, efficiently without caching?

Tags: apache-spark

As my spark program runs on more data, I think I am crashing because I'm picking up the default number of output partitions for aggregation - namely the 200. I've learned how to control this, but it seems ideally, I would set the number of output partitions based on the amount of data I'm writing. Here in lies the conundrum - I need to first call `count()` on the dataframe, and then `write` it. That means I may re-ready it from S3 twice. I could `cache` and then `count`, but I've seen spark crash when I cache this data, caching seems to use the most resources, whereas if I just write it - it can do something more optimal.

So my questions are, if you think this is a decent approach - doing a count first (the count is a proxy to the size on disk) or should you just hard code some numbers, change them when you need? And if I am going to count first, is their some clever way to optimize things so that the count and write share work? Other than caching the whole dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the count approach is actually correct way to go. Ideally you want your rdd partitions to be some considerable size like 50MB before writing. Otherwise you will end up with "small file problem".

Now if you have large data caching in memory could be hard. You could try `MEMORY_AND_DISK` but then the data will spill to disk and cause slowdown.

I have faced this predicament multiple times and every time I have chosen a "magic number" for the number of partitions. The number is parameterized so when I need to change I don't need to change the code, rather pass the different parameter.

If you know your datasize is generally in a particular range you could set the partition number hard coded. It is not ideal but gets the job done.

Also you could pump the metrics like size of the data in s3 and if that breaches some threshold raise an alarm then someone could change the partition number manually.

In generally if you keep the partition number moderately high like 5000 for approximately 500GB data that works for a large range i.e from 300GB to 1.2TB amount of data. This means probably you don't need to change the partition number too often if you have moderate inflow of data.

Comment: I've just learned about the rdd `countApprox` function (http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD) did you ever try this? To slow, to inaccurate?

Comment: Yeah I tried them but those functions don't work very well. There are bunch of questions regarding those issues